# Two accusative objects conflict in a German sentence?

Tags: accusative, reflexive

According to dictionaries **sich über jdn./etw. beklagen** means **to complain about sb./sth.**

I want to complain about myself, then how could I use?

> Ich beklage mich über mich.

This is an unusual usage, but I want to know if it is a grammatically correct one.

Comment: I have (hopefully) clarified the question with the closing comment.

Comment: The strange apparence of this construction can be avoided by using a different phrase (also somewhat  dated, but apparently still claiming its realm): *Ich [hadere](https://www.dwds.de/wb/hadern#gb-1) mit mir*.

Answer (score 7):

Your example is grammatically correct.

> Ich beklage mich über mich.

*Über mich* isn't a second accusative object but a prepositional object. The preposition *über* comes in two flavours with different meaning:

> Wo ist Erwin? — Er beklagt sich gerade über uns über den Lärm.

*Where is Erwin? — He's complaining above, about the noise.*

*über uns* is **über+dative**, meaning "**above** us"

*über den Lärm* is **über+accusative**, meaning "**about** the noise"

Comment: I've for the first time heard "über uns" means "above us", I thought "über uns " means in english "about us".

Comment: It can mean both. *Uns* can be both dative and accusative. Here it's dative and that has to be guessed from the other *über*, which is with accusative. Having both mean "about" has to be written as *über uns **und** den Lärm.*

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence is correct.

Analysis of your sentence:

- **Ich**
  subject
  a mandatory complement of the verb (telling us **who** is complaining)
  personal pronoun
  nominative case, singular, 1<sup>st</sup> person
- **beklage**
  finit verb (telling us **what** is going on in this sentence)
  matching to the subject in number and person: singular, 1<sup>st</sup> person
  present tense
- **mich**
  accusative object
  a mandatory complement of the verb (needed because *beklagen* is a reflexive verb. This *mich* is not telling anything new, it just again tells us **who** is complaining)
  reflexive pronoun
  matching to the subject in number and person: singular, 1<sup>st</sup> person
- **über mich**
  prepositional object
  an optional complement of the verb (telling us **about who** the subject is complaining)

  - **über**
    preposition (telling us, that someone is saying something **about** somebody)
  - **mich**
    accusative object
    a mandatory complement of the preposition (telling us about **who** the subject is complaining)
    personal pronoun
    accusative case, singular, 1<sup>st</sup> person (there is no grammatical need for matching with the subject in number and person. It's matching only because of syntactical reasons, because source and target of complaint are equal.)

But if you want, you can also add »selbst« at the end of the sentence:

> Ich beklage mich über mich selbst.

This additional word is then part of the prepositional object which then has three words: »über mich selbst«.

- **über mich selbst**
  ...

  - **selbst**
    apposition
    an optional complement of the preposition (telling us, that the subject is complaining about him-**self**. But this information exists already in the previous word *mich*, so in fact it is redundant.)
    demonstrative pronoun (referring to both, the subject and to the accusative object inside the prepositional object. Because it is referring to two parts of speech that need to be the same, it only can be used if they really are equal, like in this sentence. You could not use it in »Hans beklagt sich über Anna <del>selbst</del>«, but you can use it in »Hans beklagt sich über sich *selbst*«)

Answer (score -1):

> I want to complain about myself.

Word for word this translates easily into:

> Ich habe Lust/das Bedürfnis zu beschweren über mich selbst.

To make that into a proper German sentence you add one word (mich) and move the verb to the end.

> Ich habe Lust **mich** über mich selbst zu beschweren.